# C# parallel threading but control by each other

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to write a program which will have 2 thread. One will download another will parse the downloaded file. The tricky part is I can not have 2 parsing thread at the same time as it is using a library technique to parse the file. Please help with a suggestion. Thank you.

```
Foreach(string filename in filenames)
{
    //start downloading thread here;
    readytoparse.Add(filename);
}

Foreach(string filename in readytoparse)
{
    //start parsing here
}
```

I ended up with the following logic

```
bool parserrunning = false;
List<string> readytoparse = new List<string>();
List<string> filenames= new List<string>();

//downloading method
Foreach(string filename in filenames)
{
    //start downloading thread here;
    readytoparse.Add(filename);
    if(parserrunning == false;
    {
        // start parser method
    }
}

//parsing method
parserrunning = true;
list<string> _readytoparse = new List<string>(readytoparse);
Foreach(string filename in _readytoparse)
{  

    //start parsing here
}
parserrunning = false;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use two separate threads? It seems like you're assuming the task will finish more quickly if you subdivide the work into more than one non-UI thread, and that's not necessarily the best logic.

Why not use a single non-UI thread, and have that thread do all the downloading, then all the parsing?

Comment: You need a basic parallelism tutorial. Many approaches are possible, all of which have been covered many times.

Comment: I already have that code done. That code is slow. It take 5 hours. I wanna minimize it

Comment: I really don't think that the reason that code is slow is because it's executing in one thread instead of two. I'd suggest asking about that code on Code Review, rather than trying to parallelize code that shouldn't be.

Comment: If you already have code why is it not here? As asked, the question demands a tutorial.

Comment: Do you want to download all (or at least several) files at the same time, probably with several threads, and queue the result so parsing can be performed on one file at a time, as fast as possible after it has been downloaded?

Comment: erikH you got it right. The server does other jobs. My job is a subset of the jobs the server does. I am not willing to use more than 2 threads. I optimized the codes as much as I can. It has to download 70 zip files around 50 MB. After unzipping it is around 500 MB on average. Parsing those takes time but not that much. My one thread code waits to parse until the download ends. I want to have 2 threads 1 for downloading 1 for parsing.

Comment: please check my answer, if you need I can send you sample

Comment: Mehdi thank you for your answer. I am going through it and will implement to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yousuf, your "question" is pretty vague. You could take an approach where your main thread downloads the files, then each time a file finishes downloading, spawns a worker thread to parse that file. There is the Task API or QueueUserWorkItem for this sort of thing. I suppose it's possible that you could end up with an awful lot of worker threads running concurrently this way, which isn't necessarily the key to getting the work done faster and could negatively impact other concurrent work on the computer.

If you want to limit this to two threads, you might consider having the download thread write the file name into a queue each time a download finishes. Then your parser thread monitors that queue (wake up every x seconds, check the queue to see if there's anything to do, do the work, check the queue again, if there's nothing to do, go back to sleep for x seconds, repeat).

If you want the parser to be resilient, make that queue persistent (a database, MSMQ, a running text file on disk--*something* persistent). That way, if there is an interruption (computer crashes, program crashes, power loss), the parser can start right back up where it left off.

Code synchronization comes into play in the sense that you obviously cannot have the parser trying to parse a file that the downloader is still downloading, and if you have two threads using a queue, then you obviously have to protect that queue from concurrent access.

Whether you use Monitors or Mutexes, or QueueUserWorkItem or the Task API is sort of academic. There is plenty of support in the .NET framework for synchronizing and parallelizing units of work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding all of the heart-ache in doing this yourself with any primatives and use a library designed for this kind of thing.

I recommend Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx).

Here's the code:

```
var query =
    from filename in filenames.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    from file in Observable.Start(() => /* read file */, Scheduler.Default)
    from parsed in Observable.Start(() => /* parse file */, Scheduler.Default)
    select new
    {
        filename,
        parsed,
    };

query.Subscribe(fp =>
{
    /* Do something with finished file */
});
```

Very simple.

If your parsing library is single threaded only, then add this line:

```
var els = new EventLoopScheduler();
```

And then replace `Scheduler.Default` with `els` on the parsing line.